# Can't find: BlowfishPasswordHasher Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I just downloaded CakePHP and was following the tutorials to get the basics. Everything was going ok, until I started with this Authentication system.

If you go to the following url, and to the password hashing block ( of code ).

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout

you will see:

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
    $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
    $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
    );
}
return true;
}
```

The issue is when I run this, is that I get a Fatal Error on that Line:

Fatal error: Class 'BlowfishPasswordHasher' not found in /Users/myUser/Sites/cake/app/Model/User.php on line 29

This is the line (to be precise):

```
$passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
```

Why isn't it seeing that file ?

In my PHPStorm IDE, when I alt+click on it, it goes to the correct file located in:

/Users/myUser/Sites/cake/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BlowfishPasswordHasher.php

Anyone else having issues with this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a small comment: I have also tried: SimplePasswordHasher(), but it is giving the same error. ( the file is there though ).

Comment: Which `cakephp version` are you used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put following line in your `User Model`

```
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
class User extends AppModel {
    ....
}
```

> Note : The BlowfishPasswordHasher uses a stronger hashing algorithm (bcrypt) than SimplePasswordHasher (sha1) and provides per user salts. The SimplePasswordHasher will be removed as of CakePHP version 3.0

Comment: You rock man, Thanks. Odd that it isn't stated in the tutorial.

Comment: If you look closely @BiGGiE0344 you'll notice that this very same line can be found in the code snippet in the docs that you've linked.