# cakePHP class blowfishpasswordhasher not found

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to implement blowfish password hasher in my cakePHP app. I've followed along with the tutorial.

When trying to add a new user I'm getting a fatal error when I try to instantiate a new BlowfishPasswordHasher class in the beforeFilter function of my user model.  The error states :Class 'BlowfishPasswordHasher' not found.

I saw the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960376/cant-find-blowfishpasswordhasher-cakephp) but it looks like I have everything setup correctly.

Here is relevant code in my app/Controller/appController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

public $components = array(
    'Flash',
    'RequestHandler',
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' =>array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'username',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ),

            ),

        ),
        'loginRedirect' => '/trails',
        'logoutRedirect' => '/',
    ),
);
```

app/Model/User.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Conroller/Component/Auth');

class User extends AppModel {

public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash($this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
    }
return true;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a spelling mistake:

```
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Conroller/Component/Auth');
```

Change this to:

```
App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
```

There's no folder called `Conroller` and therefore, it's unable to locate the BlowFish library file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That fixed it.  I have looked over this code probably 50 times and couldn't find the mistake.  Knew it had to be something simple.  Good eye!!!

Comment: Pretty sure every developer has faced such an issue at some point, haha. No big deal. :)